# Insert data into different spreadsheets in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

So basically what I want is to create a xls file inside netsuite cabinet. I know the basic of creation excel inside cabinet.

I can do it like :

```
var xlsFile = nlapiCreateFile('myxlsfile.xls', 'EXCEL',nlapiEncrypt(someString, 'base64'));
xlsFile.setFolder(destinationfolderID);
var fileID = nlapiSubmitFile(xlsFile);
```

But, I was just wondering if is there any way to insert data into different spreadsheets in xls file.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string based on number of rows or something, and then save it using the function you have there... not sure under what criteria you would want to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your response @pipechang. I did that but the only issue is that I want to put the dynamic data in different spreadsheets like `sheet1`, `sheet2` and so on. As you have instructed I see your point but what it basically doing is, it is putting all the string data in the same sheet in row by row order. So is there any work around to make this happen. I mean can I create different sheets with dynamic data?

Comment: You would have to use a library for that. The only ones I was able to find were used in node, so they might work or not - NS javascript is not native javascript .

This seems like it could do the job.

https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls